# how to show loading while changing image's source

Tags: javascript

I have images in javascript array I change that on previous and next button click but after changing source it takes some time i want to display loading while changing source is complete

here is Code

```
`imgsrc = url + "Convension/images/" + arrImages[i].CategoryName + "/mOver/" + arrImages[i].Name;
                    $("#Imgconvention").attr('src', imgsrc);`
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where are you having difficulties? Are you just asking us to write the code for you?

Comment: Question is so simple i want to display loading while changing source of image

Comment: I cant understand what are you saying

Answer (score 0):

You can display your image inside a `div`, and set a "loading" `background-image` via CSS on that `div`.

HTML:

```
<div class="imageContainer"><img id="Imgconvention" src="" / ></div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageContainer
{
    background-image: url(your-loading-image.png);
}
```

Once `your-loading-image.png` has loaded, it will be visible whenever the `src` of your image has been changed to an image that has yet been loaded by the browser.

An alternative would be to preloading your images using JavaScript. This can eliminate the delay for the user (although you might just want to preload the previous/next image if there are lots of them and/or they are large.